# Girar imagem PPM em 90 graus em C

Tags: c, imagem, processamento-de-imagens, pgm

Bom, estou tentando girar em 90° uma imagem no formato PPM NxM na linguagem C e não estou encontrando uma maneira de fazer isso. O programa lê a imagem de um arquivo externo e acaba criando outro, ambos em formato PPM. Os dados anteriores são armazenados nas variáveis locais e os pixels da imagem numa matriz bidimensional de `struct`s com 3 valores. Abaixo segue um exemplo do código.

```c
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct imagem IMAGEM;

struct imagem{
    int r,g,b;
};

IMAGEM **M;

int main(){
    FILE *arq;
    FILE *arq2;
    arq = fopen("imagem.ppm","r");
    int g, h, i, j, maxCor;
    char string[6];
    fscanf(arq,"%s",string);
    fscanf(arq,"%d",&g);
    fscanf(arq,"%d",&h);
    fscanf(arq,"%d",&maxCor);
    if (g >= h){
        M = malloc(g * sizeof(IMAGEM));
        for (i=0;i<g;i++)
            M[i] = malloc(g * sizeof(IMAGEM));
    } else {
        M = malloc(h * sizeof(IMAGEM));
        for (i=0;i<g;i++)
            M[i] = malloc(h * sizeof(IMAGEM));
    }

    for (i=0;i<g;i++){
        for(j=0;j<h;j++){
            fscanf(arq,"%d",&M[i][j].r);
            fscanf(arq,"%d",&M[i][j].g);
            fscanf(arq,"%d",&M[i][j].b);
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
    arq2 = fopen("imagemsaida.ppm","w");
    fprintf(arq2,"%s\n",string);
    fprintf(arq2,"%d\n",g);
    fprintf(arq2,"%d\n",h); 
    fprintf(arq2,"%d\n",maxCor);
    for(i=0;i<g;i++){
        for(j=0;j<h;j++){
            fprintf(arq2,"%d\n",M[i][j].r);
            fprintf(arq2,"%d\n",M[i][j].g);
            fprintf(arq2,"%d\n",M[i][j].b);
        }
    }
    fclose(arq2);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Em qualquer caso a tua matriz `M` representa um quadrado (g*g ou h*h). Tens que fazer o primeiro `malloc` com g (ou h) e o segundo com h (ou g).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, essa `struct` que você chamou de `imagem` e `IMAGEM`, na verdade é apenas um pixel. Então vamos renomear ela:

```c
typedef struct pixel PIXEL;

struct pixel {
    int r, g, b;
};
```

Melhor ainda, combinar o `struct` e o `typedef` em uma coisa só:

```c
typedef struct PIXEL {
    int r, g, b;
} PIXEL;
```

Segundo, com base nisso, vamos criar um outro `struct` de imagem para poder organizar melhor os nossos dados:

```c
typedef struct IMAGEM {
    int largura;
    int altura;
    int maxcor;
    PIXEL *pixels;
} IMAGEM;
```

Terceiro, ter toda a lógica dentro do `main` não é muito bom, pois o código fica confuso. A solução para isso é modularizar o seu código, dividindo-o em funções.

Então, vamos separar uma função para criar uma imagem:

```c
IMAGEM *nova_imagem(int largura, int altura, int maxcor) {
    IMAGEM *imagem = (IMAGEM *) malloc(sizeof(IMAGEM));
    imagem->pixels = (PIXEL *) malloc(largura * altura * sizeof(PIXEL));
    imagem->largura = largura;
    imagem->altura = altura;
    imagem->maxcor = maxcor;
    return imagem;
}
```

Observe que a imagem criada sempre tem como tamanho `largura * altura`. Compare isso com o seu código anterior:

```c
if (g >= h){
    M = malloc(g * sizeof(IMAGEM));
    for (i=0;i<g;i++)
        M[i] = malloc(g * sizeof(IMAGEM));
} else {
    M = malloc(h * sizeof(IMAGEM));
    for (i=0;i<g;i++)
        M[i] = malloc(h * sizeof(IMAGEM));
}
```

Observe que no seu código anterior, ele vai criar a imagem com o tamanho `h * h` ou `g * g`, sendo que você queria ou `g * h` ou `h * g`. Mas como os dois laços daí vão de 0 até `g - 1` você vai reservar uma área desnecessária no caso do `else`. Além disso, você está alocando um monte de memória, linha por linha e colocando em vários ponteiros diferentes, quando é mais simples e mais eficiente colocar tudo em um blocão só, tal como a minha função acima faz.

Bem, prosseguindo com o nosso programa, temos que ter uma função que libera a memória da imagem criada:

```c
void destruir_imagem(IMAGEM *imagem) {
    free(imagem->pixels);
    free(imagem);
}
```

Além disso, precisamos de uma forma de acessar os pixels da imagem tanto para leitura dos seus valores quanto para escrita. Isso é equivalente aos seus `&M[i][j]`, mas como fizemos uma só alocação para todos os pixels, temos que usar algo mais esperto:

```c
PIXEL *pixel_da_imagem(IMAGEM *imagem, int x, int y) {
    return &(imagem->pixels[y * imagem->largura + x]);
}
```

Esta fórmula `y * imagem->largura + x` pode parecer esquisita, mas é porque cada linha corresponde a um bloquinho de `largura` pixels, sendo todas as linhas armazenadas contiguamente na memória em um único blocão. Assim sendo, cada posição que variar no `y` ocasiona uma variação de `largura` posições dentro do blocão.

A vantagem deste método é que não precisamos alocar cada linha uma por uma no laço `for`, o que simplifica a alocação e a desalocação das imagens, otimiza o uso de memória e também o desempenho ao garantir que todos os pixels da imagem estarão na mesma região de memória. A desvantagem é que a fórmula para acessar os pixels fica um pouquinho mais complicadinha, mas só um pouquinho.

Com isso, agora vamos criar uma função para ler os dados da figura de um arquivo:

```c
IMAGEM *ler_arquivo_ppm_p3(const char *nome_arquivo) {
    FILE *arq = fopen(nome_arquivo, "r");
    if (arq == NULL) return NULL;
    int largura, altura, maxcor, x, y;
    IMAGEM *imagem = NULL;
    char formato[6];
    fgets(formato, 6, arq);
    if (strcmp("P3\n", formato) == 0) {
        fscanf(arq, "%d", &largura);
        fscanf(arq, "%d", &altura);
        fscanf(arq, "%d", &maxcor);
        imagem = nova_imagem(largura, altura, maxcor);
        for (y = 0; y < altura; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < largura; x++) {
                PIXEL *p = pixel_da_imagem(imagem, x, y);
                fscanf(arq, "%d", &(p->r));
                fscanf(arq, "%d", &(p->g));
                fscanf(arq, "%d", &(p->b));
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return imagem;
}
```

Observe que estou usando o `fgets` para ler o formato. O motivo disso é que e assim não corro o risco de ter um *buffer overflow* ao ler o formato da imagem.

Também esta função aceita arquivos apenas no [subformato P3 do formato PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html#plainppm) (sem linhas de comentários iniciados por `#`), que acredito que seja o formato que você quer. Ela verifica se o cabeçalho do arquivo começa com `P3` e rejeita o arquivo se este não for o caso, retornando `NULL`. `NULL` também é retornado se o arquivo não puder ser aberto por algum motivo (o caso mais comum é quando o arquivo não existe).

Entretanto, a função não aceita comentários no arquivo (linhas iniciadas por `#`) e provavelmente algo ruim vai acontecer se ela ler um arquivo incompleto, truncado, defeituoso ou mal-formatado que mesmo assim tenha o cabeçalho "`P3`". Arrumar estes detalhes dá algum trabalho a mais, mas não é tão difícil assim também. Idem para modificar a função para aceitar imagens em outros formatos.

E agora a função que escreve o arquivo:

```c
void salvar_arquivo_ppm_p3(const char *nome_arquivo, IMAGEM *imagem) {
    FILE *arq = fopen(nome_arquivo, "w");
    int x, y;
    fprintf(arq, "P3\n%d %d\n%d", imagem->largura, imagem->altura, imagem->maxcor);
    for (y = 0; y < imagem->altura; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < imagem->largura; x++) {
            PIXEL *p = pixel_da_imagem(imagem, x, y);
            fprintf(arq, "\n%d %d %d", p->r, p->g, p->b);
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
}
```

Nada de muito surpreendente aqui. Mas há duas diferenças importantes em relação ao seu código. A primeira é os `\n` e o espaço do cabeçalho que você esqueceu entre o nome do formato, a largura, a altura e o `maxcor` da imagem. Sem esses caracteres, o arquivo gerado seria mal-formado.

A segunda diferença é mais cosmética, eu apenas combinei alguns dos seus `fprintf`s seguidos em um número menor de `fprintf`s.

Feito isso, agora vem a parte legal. Rotacionar a figura em 90 graus. Eu poderia usar um processo aonde a imagem original é alterada ou aonde uma cópia com as alterações é feita e a imagem original é preservada. Acho a segunda alternativa melhor:

```c
IMAGEM *rotacionar_90_graus_direita(IMAGEM *original) {
    int x, y;
    int h = original->altura, w = original->largura;
    IMAGEM *rotacionada = nova_imagem(h, w, original->maxcor);
    for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            PIXEL *p1 = pixel_da_imagem(original, x, y);
            PIXEL *p2 = pixel_da_imagem(rotacionada, h - y - 1, x);
            p2->r = p1->r;
            p2->g = p1->g;
            p2->b = p1->b;
        }
    }
    return rotacionada;
}
```

Aqui há de se notar que para criar a imagem rotacionada, eu inverti os parâmetros da altura e da largura. Isso é intecional, uma vez que a imagem rotacionada tem como altura, a largura da original e vice-versa. O `maxcol` da imagem rotacionada é o mesmo da original.

Os pixels da imagem rotacionada são definidos por meio da [transformada/função linear](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transforma%C3%A7%C3%A3o_linear) `T(x, y) = (y, -x)`, que é a transformada linear de rotação para a direita em 90 graus. Valores negativos são deslocados para não sairem da faixa de posições apropriadas, de forma que `-x` se torna `w - x - 1`. Da mesma forma `-y` se tornaria `h - y - 1`. Assim sendo, eis as funções de transformação interessantes:

- `t(x, y) = (y, w - x - 1)`: Rotação 90 graus à esquerda (sentido anti-horário).
- `t(x, y) = (h - y - 1, x)`: Rotação 90 graus à direita (sentido horário).
- `t(x, y) = (w - x - 1, h - y - 1)`: Rotação em 180 graus.
- `t(x, y) = (w - x - 1, y)`: Reflexão na horizontal.
- `t(x, y) = (x, h - y - 1)`: Reflexão na vertical.
- `t(x, y) = (y, x)`: Reflexão na diagonal principal.
- `t(x, y) = (h - y - 1, w - x - 1)`: Reflexão na diagonal secundária.
- `t(x, y) = (x, y)`: Nenhuma alteração é realizada.

Outros tipos de transformadas (cisalhamentos, deformações, alargamentos, projeções trapezóides, projeções cilíndricas, rotações em ângulos arbitrários, etc) demandam fórmulas mais complicadas.

Observe também que os valores dos pixels são simplesmente copiados. Mas se você fazer algo diferente do que apenas copiar os valores dos pixels (em especial se você também olhar para os pixels vizinhos ou para a distribuição estatística dos pixels na imagem), poderá fazer efeitos tais como inverter cores, converter para preto-e-branco, realçar cores, fazer filtragem por cores, recolorir, eliminação de ruído, ajuste de brilho e contraste, detecção de bordas, segmentação e reconhecimento de objetos, etc.

Agora você só precisa combinar tudo isso para fazer o seu programa para rotacionar imagens:

```c
int main() {
    IMAGEM *original = ler_arquivo_ppm_p3("imagem.ppm");
    if (original == NULL) {
        printf("Arquivo nao eh PPM P3 ou nao existe");
        return 1;
    }
    IMAGEM *rotacionada = rotacionar_90_graus_direita(original);
    salvar_arquivo_ppm_p3("imagemsaida.ppm", rotacionada);
    destruir_imagem(original);
    destruir_imagem(rotacionada);
    return 0;
}
```

Olha só que legal! O seu `main` ficou extremamente simples e intuitivo de se entender!

Juntando tudo, olha só como o seu código fica:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct PIXEL {
    int r, g, b;
} PIXEL;

typedef struct IMAGEM {
    int largura;
    int altura;
    int maxcor;
    PIXEL *pixels;
} IMAGEM;

IMAGEM *nova_imagem(int largura, int altura, int maxcor) {
    IMAGEM *imagem = (IMAGEM *) malloc(sizeof(IMAGEM));
    imagem->pixels = (PIXEL *) malloc(largura * altura * sizeof(PIXEL));
    imagem->largura = largura;
    imagem->altura = altura;
    imagem->maxcor = maxcor;
    return imagem;
}

void destruir_imagem(IMAGEM *imagem) {
    free(imagem->pixels);
    free(imagem);
}

PIXEL *pixel_da_imagem(IMAGEM *imagem, int x, int y) {
    return &(imagem->pixels[y * imagem->largura + x]);
}

IMAGEM *ler_arquivo_ppm_p3(const char *nome_arquivo) {
    FILE *arq = fopen(nome_arquivo, "r");
    if (arq == NULL) return NULL;
    int largura, altura, maxcor, x, y;
    IMAGEM *imagem = NULL;
    char formato[6];
    fgets(formato, 6, arq);
    if (strcmp("P3\n", formato) == 0) {
        fscanf(arq, "%d", &largura);
        fscanf(arq, "%d", &altura);
        fscanf(arq, "%d", &maxcor);
        imagem = nova_imagem(largura, altura, maxcor);
        for (y = 0; y < altura; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < largura; x++) {
                PIXEL *p = pixel_da_imagem(imagem, x, y);
                fscanf(arq, "%d", &(p->r));
                fscanf(arq, "%d", &(p->g));
                fscanf(arq, "%d", &(p->b));
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return imagem;
}

void salvar_arquivo_ppm_p3(const char *nome_arquivo, IMAGEM *imagem) {
    FILE *arq = fopen(nome_arquivo, "w");
    int x, y;
    fprintf(arq, "P3\n%d %d\n%d", imagem->largura, imagem->altura, imagem->maxcor);
    for (y = 0; y < imagem->altura; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < imagem->largura; x++) {
            PIXEL *p = pixel_da_imagem(imagem, x, y);
            fprintf(arq, "\n%d %d %d", p->r, p->g, p->b);
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
}

IMAGEM *rotacionar_90_graus_direita(IMAGEM *original) {
    int x, y;
    int h = original->altura, w = original->largura;
    IMAGEM *rotacionada = nova_imagem(h, w, original->maxcor);
    for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            PIXEL *p1 = pixel_da_imagem(original, x, y);
            PIXEL *p2 = pixel_da_imagem(rotacionada, h - y - 1, x);
            p2->r = p1->r;
            p2->g = p1->g;
            p2->b = p1->b;
        }
    }
    return rotacionada;
}

int main() {
    IMAGEM *original = ler_arquivo_ppm_p3("imagem.ppm");
    if (original == NULL) {
        printf("Arquivo nao eh PPM P3 ou nao existe");
        return 1;
    }
    IMAGEM *rotacionada = rotacionar_90_graus_direita(original);
    salvar_arquivo_ppm_p3("imagemsaida.ppm", rotacionada);
    destruir_imagem(original);
    destruir_imagem(rotacionada);
    return 0;
}
```

Vamos testar isso tudo. Eis uma imagem PPM P3 bem pequena e simples:

```
P3
4 2
255
255 255 255   255   0   0     0 255   0     0   0 255
  0   0   0     0 255 255   255   0 255   255 255   0
```

Eis o resultado após executar o programa:

```
P3
2 4
255
0 0 0
255 255 255
0 255 255
255 0 0
255 0 255
0 255 0
255 255 0
0 0 255
```

Vamos visualizar? Aqui vão as duas imagens lado a lado (aumentadas com um zoom de 1000%, uma vez que cada uma delas têm apenas 8 pixels e ficaria muito pequeno para ver direito):

- Imagem original: [image: Original - zoom 1000%]
- Imagem rotacionada 90 graus para a direita: [image: Rotacionada - zoom 1000%]

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta, sanou minha dúvida. Porém, me surgiu outra curiosidade: Como faço para "desfocar a imagem"?

Comment: @DJM_JM Uma forma simples é você pegar o valor das cores do pixel, somar com o valor dos pixels vizinhos, tirar a média deles e colocar o valor resultante no pixel da imagem nova. Para desfocar ainda mais, pode ser não só dos pixels vizinhos, mas de todos os pixels dentro de um círculo de raio `r` centrado no pixel de origem.